# Angular Cli with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, angular-cli

I am trying to setup jenkins job for Angular cli project. I am getting 406 error. This stuff works in my local. The issue is only when I run from jenkins. Can someone please guide me here.

npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code E406

npm ERR! Registry returned 406 for GET on http://myRepository.com:someport/artifactory/blahblah/@angular%2fcommon

Comment: Do you use the same version of Node/NPM in Jekins as on local? Also `6.6.0` is getting old nowadays.

Comment: Thanks Yuri! yes looks like I was on 6.9.0 in my local. I need to upgrade node version on jenkins and see if this issue gets resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need Node > 6.9 and npm > 3.0 for angular CLI.

> Verify that you are running at least node 6.9.x and npm 3.x.x by
>   running node -v and npm -v in a terminal/console window. Older
>   versions produce errors, but newer versions are fine.

source: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart